# How do I trap the mouse pointer within a VirtualBox Guest OS?

Tags: virtualbox, mouse

I'm on a Mac Mini 2011 with VirtualBox installed. I have Windows 7 running as a Guest OS.

My question: How do I "trap" my mouse pointer within Windows? In other words, I don't want my mouse to move outside to the Host OS. Ideally, I would be able to press the Host key to "untrap" my mouse.

The purpose: I'm playing Warcraft 3 in the Guest OS and I can't scroll the screen since the mouse keeps jumping to the Host OS instead of scrolling the screen. This happens even in full-screen mode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Select `Disable Mouse Integration` from VirtualBox's **Machine** menu. Next, **click** within the guest OS to `capture` the mouse.

[image: capture]

Answer (score 5):

Use this command to make it permanent.

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "your-vm-name" --mouse ps2
```

Comment: This works with newer versions of VirtualBox